server action is not being perform by client side action in next 14
I am using next 14 app router latest version for my project. I am implementing one search functionality like below. when I search post in the expected behavior is search the result using API and get the search results that contain post. server-side action is perform in the local but not in the developement. I can see the form data in network tab but getSearchQueryResponse is not being fire.

client side
'use client'
import { getSearchQueryResponse } from '@/app/actions/index'
...
...
...
<form 
  className="group relative flex h-12" 
  onSubmit={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior
    setSearchResults({
      hitEnter: true,
      ...
    })
    // get the form data
    getSearchQueryResponse(formData)
      .then((response) => {
        // set the search results in the state
        setSearchResults({
          ...response,
          hitEnter: true,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error searching docs:', error); // Log any errors
      });
  }}
>
  <SearchIcon className="pointer-events-none absolute left-4 top-0 h-full w-5 fill-zinc-400 dark:fill-zinc-500" />
  <input
    className={classNames..}
    name='search'
    onChange={(event) => _handler(event)}
    placeholder="e.g video player"
  />

server action getSearchQueryResponse
'use server'

import { getSearchData } from "@/lib/api"

export async function getSearchQueryResponse( formData){
  const formValue = Object.fromEntries(formData)
  const response = await getSearchData(formValue.search) // api to get search data
  return response
}

